# Why does it seem that my HTML does not access my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

I am trying to make an image expand into a movable small window. The html is created with an xslt but here is the img tag that is supposed to expand when clicked. I have tried using an `onclick="functionname()"` but it says function is not defined.

```
<img class='AOIMapFir' src='/api/thumbnails/npsi?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=100&amp;height=85&amp;layer={$identifier}_{$codeLVal}' onerror="this.setAttribute('src','/api/thumbnails/edcss?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=100&amp;height=85');"></img>
```

this is the function in the javascript:

```
 NPSIMapPopUp : function(){
        $('.AOIMapFir').click(function(){


        $('#dialog').dialog({
            appendTo: ".widget",
            title: "Area of Interest",
            resizable: false,
            position: {
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: ".container"
            },
            width: "auto",
            height: "auto",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            show: { effect: "blind", duration: 200 }
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        $(".ui-widget").css({
            "font-size": +10+"px",
            "background-color": "none"
        });
        });
        }
```

I have tried using `'click .AOIMapFir' : 'NPSIMapPopUp'`at the top of the js file but when I debug I never see it enter the function with anyway I have tried. Thanks for all the help!

```
<xsl:if test="cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:resourceMetadata/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:fileInformation/gmd:MD_FileInformation/gmd:rasterTypes">
                                                        <li class="attr">
                                                            <div class="col1"></div>
                                                            <div class="col2">Raster Types</div>
                                                            <div class="col3">
                                                                <xsl:for-each select="cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:resourceMetadata/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:fileInformation/gmd:MD_FileInformation/gmd:rasterTypes">

                                                                    <!-- shift the context to the lookup elements -->
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="raster_label">
                                                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$metacard_label-top">
                                                                            <xsl:with-param name="curr-label" select="@codeList"/>
                                                                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                                                                    </xsl:variable>                     

                                                                    <xsl:choose>
                                                                        <xsl:when test=". != ''">   <!-- If the element value is not null, display it. Else display attribute value. -->
                                                                            <xsl:value-of select="." /> - <xsl:value-of select="$raster_label" /><br />
                                                                        </xsl:when>
                                                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                            <xsl:value-of select="@codeListValue" /> - <xsl:value-of select="$raster_label" /><br />
                                                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                                                    </xsl:choose>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="rasterType" select="cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:resourceMetadata/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:fileInformation/gmd:MD_FileInformation/gmd:rasterTypes"></xsl:variable>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="identifier" select="/tdf:TrustedDataObject/tdf:HandlingAssertion/tdf:HandlingStatement/edh:ExternalEdh/edh:Identifier"></xsl:variable>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="codeLVal" select="@codeListValue"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_min_long" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:westBoundLongitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_min_lat" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:southBoundLatitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_max_long" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:eastBoundLongitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_max_lat" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:northBoundLatitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <img class='AOIMapFir' src='/api/thumbnails/npsi?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=100&amp;height=85&amp;layer={$identifier}_{$codeLVal}'  ></img><!-- this works -->
                                                                    <div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable {$identifier}" style="display: none; height: auto; width: auto; font-size: 10px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">Area of Interest</span><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close" style="font-size: 10px;"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">close</span></button></div><div id="dialog" class="hide-dialog ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 81px; max-height: none; height: auto;"><img class='aoi' src='/api/thumbnails/npsi?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=400&amp;height=300&amp;layer={$identifier}_{$codeLVal}' onerror="this.setAttribute('src','/api/thumbnails/edcss?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=400&amp;height=300');"></img></div></div>
                                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                                            </div>

                                                        </li>       
                                                    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Are you debugging it and setting a break point?  Have you tried the classic sticking an alert in your function to see if it pops up when you click the image?

Comment: @dustmouse Yes I haved tried with both break point and alert. It doesn't touch the js

Comment: Where is this script being executed?  Is it in <script> tags?  Have you verified that anything else in the script block is being hit?

Comment: @dustmouse the script is a seperate file. Yes I have another image doing something similar but actually goes into the NPSIMapPopUp.js

Comment: Could you post the markup for that image?

Comment: @dustmouse its in an xslt file that has 1200 lines of code, it doesnt fit in the question. I'll post the section that has the image in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I ended up able to create a click event that worked was to bind the click function inside of the render function in the js file.

```
define(
    [ 'sandbox', 'text!../templates/unitinfo.html',
            '../collections/metacards', '../models/metacard',
            'cdpe$/metacard-view', 'cdpe_config',
            'third/jquery.mCustomScrollbar', 'third/jstree' ],
    function(sandbox, unitInfoTemplate, MetacardsCol, Metacard,
            MetacardView, cdpeConfig) {

        var AppView = sandbox.mvc
                .View({

                    unitInfoTemplate : sandbox.template
                            .parse(unitInfoTemplate),

                    collection : new MetacardsCol(),

                    events : {
                        'click .close' : function() {
                            sandbox.emit("preview-pane.close");
                        },
                        'click .mc-menu li' : 'switchTab',
                        'click .findUIC' : 'findUIC',
                        'click .newProjectBtn' : 'SubmitNewProject',
                        'click .entity-dropdown' : 'showEntityMenu',
                        'click .findMission' : 'findMission',
                        'click .oob-dropdown' : 'showOOBMenu',
                        'click .jstree-icon' : 'insertSearchIcon',
                        'click .AOIMap' : 'AOIMapPopUp',
                        'click .SAOIMap' : 'SAOIMapPopUp'

                    },



                    initialize : function() {
                        sandbox.events.bindAll(this);
                        this.collection.bind('change:html', function() {
                        });
                        $(window).scroll(
                                function() {
                                    $('.preview-pane').css('left',
                                            850 - $(window).scrollLeft());
                                });
                        $(window)
                                .resize(
                                        function() {
                                            this
                                                    .$('.mc')
                                                    .css(
                                                            'height',
                                                            $(window)
                                                                    .height()
                                                                    - 220
                                                                    + 'px')
                                                    .mCustomScrollbar(
                                                            {
                                                                theme : "cdpe-preview",
                                                                advanced : {
                                                                    updateOnContentResize : true
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                        });
                    },

                    load : function(options) {
                        sandbox.logger.info('Loading Preview Content');
                        this.$el.css('display', 'inline-block');
                        this.getMetacard(options);
                        /*
                         * var model = new Metacard( { id: object } ), that =
                         * this; model.bind('change:html', function() {
                         * that.$('.content').html(model.get('html'));
                         * that.$('.mc\\.display').metacardView(); });
                         */
                    },

                    hide : function(object) {
                        this.$el.css('display', 'none');
                    },

                    render : function(model) {
                        var that = this;
                        this.$('.mc\\.display').remove();
                        this.$('.ph').remove();
                        this.$('.content').append(
                                this.addRowShading(model.get('html')));
                        this.$('.mc\\.display').metacardView();
                        this.$('.mc').css('height',
                                $(window).height() - 220 + 'px')
                                .mCustomScrollbar({
                                    theme : "cdpe-preview",
                                    advanced : {
                                        updateOnContentResize : true
                                    }
                                });
                        this.createExpandingAttrs();

                        // this.$( '.mc\\.display'
                        // ).metacardView('setTabContent', { name:'oob',
                        // title: 'Order of Battle Hierarchy' , content:
                        // '<div id="oob_hierarchy"></div>'});
                        this.$("#oob_hierarchy").jstree({
                            "json_data" : {
                                "data" : model.get('oob-tree-json')
                            },
                            "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ],
                            "themes" : {
                                "theme" : "classic",
                                "dots" : false,
                                "icons" : true
                            }
                        }).bind("select_node.jstree",
                                function(event, data) {
                                    if (data.rslt.obj.data("unit-info")) {

                                        that.toggleUnitInfo(data.rslt.obj);
                                    }
                                });
                        // this.$( '.mc\\.display'
                        // ).metacardView('setActiveTab', { tabName: 'oob' }
                        // );
        >>>>>>>>>>>>>>> $('.AOIMapFir').click(function(){
                            Alertify.dialog.alert('clicked');
                        })
                        this.delegateEvents();
                    },

                    createExpandingAttrs : function() {
                        this.$(".attr.expand ul .toggle").bind(
                                'click',
                                function(event) {
                                    var topLine = $(this).closest("li");
                                    if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) {
                                        $(this).removeClass("closed")
                                                .addClass("open"); // toggle
                                                                    // plus/minus
                                        topLine.siblings().css("display",
                                                "list-item"); // toggle
                                                                // hidden
                                                                // lines
                                    } else {
                                        $(this).removeClass("open")
                                                .addClass("closed");
                                        topLine.siblings().css('display',
                                                'none');
                                    }
                                    return false;
                                });
                    },

                    insertSearchIcon : function(evt) {
                        var treeExists = $('.jstree-icon').html();
                        var currentTarget = $(evt.currentTarget);
                        if (treeExists != null) { // Check to see if tree
                                                    // exists
                            var elementExists = document
                                    .getElementsByClassName('oob-dropdown');
                            zero = 0;
                            if (elementExists.length == zero) { // Check to
                                                                // see if
                                                                // button is
                                                                // already
                                                                // there
                                $('.jstree-leaf')
                                        .each(
                                                function() { // If not a
                                                                // unit put
                                                                // button
                                                    var id = this.id;
                                                    if (id.indexOf("unit") == -1) {
                                                        $(this)
                                                                .prepend(
                                                                        '<button class="oob-dropdown" id="oob-button"></button>');
                                                    }
                                                });
                            }
                        }

                    },

                    getMetacard : function(options) {
                        // this.insertSearchIcon();
                        this.$('.mc\\.display').remove();
                        this.$('.ph').remove();
                        this.$('.content').append(
                                '<span class="ph">Loading</span>');
                        var self = this, model = this.collection
                                .get(options.id);
                        if (model && model.get('html')) {
                            this.render(model);
                        } else if (model) {
                            sandbox.logger
                                    .info('Model html empty, attempting fetch from server');
                            model.fetch({
                                error : function(model, jqXHR, options) {
                                    sandbox.emit('error', {
                                        action : 'initialError',
                                        jqXHR : jqXHR
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            sandbox.logger
                                    .info('Model not in local storage, fetching from server');
                            model = this.fetchMetacard(options);
                            if (model) {
                                model.once('change:html', function() {
                                    if (this.get('oob-tree-json')) {
                                        self.render(this);
                                    }
                                });
                                model.once('change:oob-tree-json',
                                        function() {
                                            if (this.get('html')) {
                                                self.render(this);
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    fetchMetacard : function(options) {
                        var metacard = (options && options.id)
                                && new Metacard({
                                    id : options.id
                                });
                        // metacard.fetch();
                        this.collection.add(metacard);
                        return metacard;
                    },

                    preview : function() {
                        this.$('.preview-pane').toggleClass('hover');
                    },

                    toggleUnitInfo : function(node) {
                        var info = node.children('.unit-info');
                        if (info.length && info.css('display') === 'none') {
                            info.css('display', 'block');
                        } else if (info.length) {
                            info.css('display', 'none');
                        } else {
                            this.showUnitInfo(node);
                        }
                    },

                    showUnitInfo : function(node) {
                        var unitInfo = node.data("unit-info"), obj = {
                            data : {}
                        }, a = node.children('a');
                        for ( var attr in unitInfo) {
                            obj.data[this.capitalise(attr)] = unitInfo[attr];
                        }
                        $(this.unitInfoTemplate(obj)).insertAfter(a);

                    },

                    switchTab : function(evt) {
                        var tab = $(evt.currentTarget), pageName = tab
                                .data('page'), page = this
                                .$('.' + pageName), activePage = this.$(
                                '.mc-menu .active').data('page');
                        // if the tab is already active, do nothing
                        if (!tab.hasClass('active')) {
                            this.$('.mc-menu .active')
                                    .removeClass('active');
                            this.$('.' + activePage).css({
                                "display" : "none"
                            });
                            tab.addClass('active')
                            page.css({
                                "display" : "block"
                            });
                        }
                    },

                    capitalise : function(string) {
                        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
                                + string.slice(1);
                    },

                    findUIC : function(evt) {
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        var uic = $(evt.currentTarget).data('uic');
                        sandbox.emit("search-submit", {
                            query : uic
                        });
                        // function (e){
                        // var thumbContainer =
                        // document.getElementById("findUIC");
                        // var thumbnail = document.createElement("img");
                        // thumbnail.onload=function() {
                        // thumbContainer.appendChild(thumbnail);
                        // }
                        // thumbnail.src = "../apps/";
                        // }
                    },

                    findMission : function(evt) {
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        var queryData = $(evt.currentTarget)
                                .data('mission');
                        var mission = "MissionAreaFacet:" + queryData;
                        sandbox.emit("search-submit", {
                            query : mission
                        });
                    },

                    SubmitNewProject : function() {
                        var proj = this.$('.projectTitle').text();

                        // var proj = node.data("projectTitle");
                        // var proj = node.data("projectTitle"), obj = {
                        // data : {} }, a = node.children('a');
                        // var unit_title =
                        // $(this.unitInfoTemplate(obj)).insertAfter(a);
                        // var proj =
                        // $(this.unitInfoTemplate(obj)).insertAfter(a);
                        Alertify.dialog.alert(proj);
                        sandbox.emit("edcss-add", proj);
                    },

                    addRowShading : function(html) {
                        var $mc = $(html);
                        $('.page', $mc)
                                .each(
                                        function(index, value) {
                                            $(this)
                                                    .children('ul')
                                                    .children('li')
                                                    .each(
                                                            function(index,
                                                                    value) {
                                                                if (index % 2 === 0) {
                                                                    $(value)
                                                                            .addClass(
                                                                                    "even")
                                                                }
                                                                ;
                                                            })
                                        });
                        return $mc;
                    },
                    SAOIMapPopUp : function(evt) {
                        $('#dialog2').dialog({
                            appendTo : ".widget",
                            title : "Area of Interest",
                            resizable : false,
                            position : {
                                my : "center",
                                at : "center",
                                of : ".container"
                            },
                            width : "auto",
                            height : "auto",
                            closeOnEscape : true,
                            show : {
                                effect : "blind",
                                duration : 200
                            }
                        });
                        // $('body').append('<img
                        // src="/api/thumbnails/edcss?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=80&amp;height=80"></img></div>');
                        $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
                        $(".ui-widget").css({
                            "font-size" : +10 + "px",
                            "background-color" : "none"
                        });
                    },
                    AOIMapPopUp : function(evt) {

                        $('#dialog').dialog({
                            appendTo : ".widget",
                            title : "Area of Interest",
                            resizable : false,
                            position : {
                                my : "center",
                                at : "center",
                                of : ".container"
                            },
                            width : "auto",
                            height : "auto",
                            closeOnEscape : true,
                            show : {
                                effect : "blind",
                                duration : 200
                            }
                        });
                        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                        $(".ui-widget").css({
                            "font-size" : +10 + "px",
                            "background-color" : "none"
                        });
                    },
                    showEntityMenu : function(evt) { // Drop down menu
                                                        // for EDCSS
                        // Note: the message column in the logtransaction
                        // file size
                        // needs to be increased for the search related
                        // query to work (10000)
                        var btn = $(evt.currentTarget);
                        zero = 0;
                        minus = -1;
                        entityName = btn.siblings('span').text(),
                                entityMap = _.where(
                                        cdpeConfig.oobEntityMap, {
                                            "edcss name" : entityName
                                        });

                        if (entityMap.length == zero) {
                            entityMap = null;
                        }

                        function getRelEnt(eMap) { // Pull each related OOB
                                                    // entity
                            if (eMap != null) {
                                var result = "";
                                var numOfObj = eMap.length;
                                for (i = 0; i < numOfObj; i++) {
                                    if (i + 1 == numOfObj) {
                                        result += '"' + eMap[i]["obs name"]
                                                + '"' + " OR " + entityName;
                                    } else {
                                        result += '"' + eMap[i]["obs name"]
                                                + '"' + " OR ";
                                    }
                                }
                                return result;
                            }
                        }

                        html = '<div class="entity-dropdown-menu">'
                                + '<ul><li class="search-exact">Search Exact Text</li>';
                        html += entityMap ? '<li class="search-related">Search Related OOB Entities</li></ul></div>'
                                : '</ul></div>'
                        $dropdown = $(html);
                        btn.addClass('open').after($dropdown);
                        // Prevents from double opening of same menu
                        btn.on('click', function(event) {
                            if (btn.find(".entity-dropdown-menu")) {
                                $dropdown.remove();
                            }
                        });

                        $(document)
                                .on(
                                        'click',
                                        function(event) { // Gets the menu
                                                            // to close when
                                                            // clicking
                                                            // anywhere else
                                            if (!$(event.target).closest(
                                                    btn).length) {
                                                if (btn.hasClass('open')
                                                        && $dropdown
                                                                .is(':visible')) {
                                                    btn.removeClass('open');
                                                    $dropdown.remove();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                        (function() { // Sets the behavior of button/menu

                            var time = 1000, timer;

                            function handlerIn() {
                                clearTimeout(timer);
                                $dropdown.stop(true).css('opacity', 1)
                                        .show();
                            }
                            function handlerOut() {
                                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                                    $dropdown.fadeOut(500);
                                    btn.removeClass('open');
                                }, time);
                            }

                            $dropdown.hover(handlerIn, handlerOut);
                            $(evt.currentTarget).hover(handlerIn,
                                    handlerOut);

                        }());

                        var fixEntNme = entityName; // Replaces / with a
                                                    // space from the
                                                    // entityName to allow
                                                    // for searching exact
                                                    // terms
                        while (fixEntNme.search("/") != minus) {
                            fixEntNme = fixEntNme.replace("/", " ");
                        }

                        entityName = fixEntNme;
                        $dropdown.on('click', '.search-exact', function() {
                            sandbox.emit("search-submit", {
                                query : entityName,
                                resetFilters : true
                            });
                        });

                        $dropdown.on('click', '.search-related',
                                function() {
                                    sandbox.emit("search-submit", {
                                        query : getRelEnt(entityMap),
                                        resetFilters : true
                                    });
                                });
                    },

                    showOOBMenu : function(evt) { // Drop down menu for
                                                    // JTDS

                        $(".oob-dropdown-menu").each(function() {
                            $(".oob-dropdown-menu").remove();
                        });
                        var btn = $(evt.currentTarget);
                        zero = 0;
                        minus = -1;
                        entityName = btn.siblings('a').text();
                        entityName2 = entityName.substring(1,
                                entityName.length);
                        entityMap = _.where(cdpeConfig.oobEntityMap, {
                            "obs name" : entityName2
                        });
                        if (entityMap.length == zero) {
                            entityMap = null;
                        }

                        function getRelEnt(eMap) { // Pull each related OOB
                                                    // entity
                            if (eMap != null) {
                                var result = "";
                                var numOfObj = eMap.length;
                                for (i = 0; i < numOfObj; i++) {
                                    if (i + 1 == numOfObj) {
                                        result += '"'
                                                + eMap[i]["edcss name"]
                                                + '"' + " OR "
                                                + entityName2;
                                    } else {
                                        result += '"'
                                                + eMap[i]["edcss name"]
                                                + '"' + " OR ";
                                    }
                                }
                                return result;
                            }
                        }

                        html = '<div class="oob-dropdown-menu">'
                                + '<ul><li class="search-exact">Search Exact Text</li>';
                        html += entityMap ? '<li class="search-related">Search Related EDCSS Entities</li></ul></div>'
                                : '</ul></div>'
                        $dropdown1 = $(html);
                        btn.addClass('open').before($dropdown1);

                        // Prevents from double opening of same menu
                        btn.on('click', function(event) {
                            $(".oob-dropdown.open").each(
                                    function() {
                                        $(".oob-dropdown.open")
                                                .removeClass('open');
                                    });
                        });

                        $(document)
                                .on(
                                        'click',
                                        function(event) { // Gets the menu
                                                            // to close when
                                                            // clicking
                                                            // anywhere else
                                            if (!$(event.target).closest(
                                                    btn).length) {
                                                if (btn.hasClass('open')
                                                        && $dropdown1
                                                                .is(':visible')) {
                                                    btn.removeClass('open');
                                                    $dropdown1.remove();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                        (function() { // Sets the behavior of button/menu

                            var time = 1000, timer;

                            function handlerIn() {
                                clearTimeout(timer);
                                $dropdown1.stop(true).css('opacity', 1)
                                        .show();
                            }
                            function handlerOut() {
                                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                                    $dropdown1.fadeOut(500);
                                    btn.removeClass('open');
                                }, time);
                            }

                            $dropdown1.hover(handlerIn, handlerOut);
                            $(evt.currentTarget).hover(handlerIn,
                                    handlerOut);

                        }());

                        $dropdown1.on('click', '.search-exact', function() {
                            sandbox.emit("search-submit", {
                                query : entityName2,
                                resetFilters : true
                            });
                        });

                        $dropdown1.on('click', '.search-related',
                                function() {
                                    sandbox.emit("search-submit", {
                                        query : getRelEnt(entityMap),
                                        resetFilters : true
                                    });
                                });

                    }
                }); // End AppView

        return AppView;
    });
```